# Is it possible to reset the input to an AudioKit AKNode?

Tags: audiokit

I'm building an app with AudioKit where I went to be able to re-order the processing chain occasionally. E.g., I might have "wav" -> "reverb" -> "filter" and I want to swap things around so I have "wav" -> "filter" -> "reverb".

What I'd like to do is call AudioKit.stop(), replumb the inputs to existing nodes, then call AudioKit.start() again. However, it doesn't look to me like you can change the input to a node beyond the constructor, so I then need to copy the state of each node, create a new one with the same state, and then setup my chain again.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this without having to destroy and remake nodes with the same params each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example I'd consider just going with wav->reverb->filter->reverb and then bypassing the reverb you don't want to use. A bypassed effect should not bear any burden on your CPU, so it should be fine. That solves your example, but for a more general solution, yeah, you have to rebuild the entire chain. Members of the core team are working on this very issue, but for now, I think this answer will have to suffice.